# Wrapped Key Exchange Between Online and Offline Clients

Tags: web, cryptography

I want some insight on how I would exchange encryption keys between clients where key is locally stored on a client's workspace and that client is currently offline and another client who requests access to the encryption key

I have tried using a link to queue the action to make the clients exchange keys when both peers online but that would have been too dependent on both peers to be online